TL431 SMPS Modification is Unstable
I have a 32 V SMPS with a TL431 with an optocoupler as output regulator,

Image Source:https://electrosemic.com/tl431-calculator/
It had 118 kΩ as R1 and 10 kΩ as R2 to create 32 V DC at output.
First I used a 100 kΩ as R1 to regulate output down to 27 V to make it suitable for a buck regulator so I can adjust the output and it worked fine,
Now I decided to ditch the buck regulator and used a 50 kΩ as R1 potentiometer for 2.5 V to ~14 V output, but the output is not stable, it switches on and off at nearly 1 Hz like if I connect a LED to it, LED would blink every second for very short duration then stay off till it blinks again.
How do I make it stable? SMPS have no other components to suggest something like undervoltage protection that might be switching it off, just the TL431.
Main Controller: Reads LTA504SJ

Video of SMPS in question: https://youtube.com/shorts/L64sysm06cc?feature=shared

No other components? There must be a primary side switching device and electronics to drive it...

@Unimportant "to suggest something like undervoltage protection"

Primary side driver (chip?) might have a minimum duty cycle, etc... We can't tell if you hide it from us.

I'm not sure I quite understand how you're defining stability here. If your concern is about simply the 1Hz, there's really no way we know what's going on with your input side without more details. If you're concerned about your transient behaviors, this is probably more answerable but we need to understand what exactly you're seeing.

@Colin tried explaining it better this time

Wait, are you modifying an existing supply instead of designing your own? In many cases you can't just arbitrarily change feedback, since the stability of the regulator depends on the compensation of the feedback system. Please edit the question to make it clear that you're modifying an existing supply. A reverse-engineered schematic would be appreciated, as would be a picture of the PCB.

I can't find a datasheet for that controller so I can't tell for sure but here's a speculation:
Many SMPS topologies, in order to power the primary side controller, charge a capacitor trough a high value resistor or some other small current source in the controller itself. Once voltage is high enough the controller starts and a second winding on the primary side then feeds the controller.
By trying to lower the output voltage you are also lowering the voltage this primary winding produces until it's too low to keep the controller powered and it shuts down.
The cap will then slowly recharge trough the aforementioned resistor/current source and the cycle repeats.

Now that I think about it, I am 99% sure this is the case, it is stable above 25V when R1 is above 100kΩ, I am switching back to buck regulator at output

@asim Your other option is to boost the aux winding on the primary to have enough voltage, or just rewind the transformer for your new secondary voltage.

@winny you have no idea how lazy I am
